# JQuery selector in IE 7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7, backwards-compatibility

I'm having trouble with a specific selector in IE 7 and 8.  This works in Chrome, Safari, IE 9, and Firefox:

```
$('span[id*="import"][style*="width:100%"]').hide();
```

However, in IE 7/8 the `[style*=""]` doesn't seem to work at all.  I can't even get

```
$('span[style*="width"]');
```

to return anything, which it certainly should.

The width of 100% is the only thing differentiating the spans that I'm looking for on the page.

Any help?

Comment: have you tried removing the `"`s?

Comment: can you post your code and css?

Comment: I can't post the code... with the code-behind, css, and jquery, it's well over 2,000 lines.  Suffice it to say, there are numerous spans on the page at any given time, and many have width = 50% / width = 100% with the id name containing "import"

Comment: you have more than one element with the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try differentiating by class and not by style.

Not all browsers have all the styles the same way. Some browsers turn `%` into `px`

So make all the spans that have `width: 100%` have a certain class which you can then manipulate:

```
$('.width100Class').doSomething(...)
```

Comment: The HTML source (and hence the attributes) should still be the same (at least I think this is how the attribute selector works, I'm not sure though). But of course using classes is much better for a couple of reasons.

Comment: I agree with the solution but then I don't like the fact that I need to have a dummy or an extra class just for selection purposes. Also, if an element is sized programatically, then what?

Comment: The spans are sized in the code behind, a dummy class would be possible, but i liked this method for this particular purpose.  in the html source for IE 7/8 the difference is that it's "width: 100%" as opposed to "width:100%" which is fine, however IE 7/8 cannot even find a style containing "width" though it's clear that it is there.

Comment: @Mrchief: Selecting elements by *part of* their inline style declaration is not the most efficient way to do things. If you need to work with those elements in JavaScript and all you have is *this*, then considering to include a separate CSS class that replaces the inline declaration would be a smart move, IMHO.

Comment: @Brandon, see @Tomalak's comment and take it to heart.

Comment: I'm working on changing that I suppose, but in the code-behind it seems silly to be making comparisons and then changing between two different sets of classes as opposed to setting the width of an asp panel.  It makes more sense on the html-source side, but I'm not sure about the code-behind side.

Comment: Also, while this should alleviate the problem, it still doesn't answer why this doesn't work in IE 7/8 ... is it just not a supported feature...?

Comment: @Brandon. as i stated in my answer and in my comment to @Mrchief's answer. there is a bug in IE 8. try using classes instead of style selectors

Comment: Oh, i didn't catch that it was a bug... what I mean is I see that browsers handle style different ways, but even changing to complement the way IE8 handled the style didn't fix anything.

Comment: @Brandon -- again -- do not use styles for selecting. also to repeat my comment from the OP -- do you have multiple elements with the same id??

Comment: Yes, it's a dynamic gridview, most have generated names.  Unfortunately, setting a class with a width attribute isn't working in any browser... the CSS width is showing up in the developer's tools, but the span is shrinking to the size of the content regardless.

Comment: you cannot have multiply elements with the same id in the DOM. it can screw up the selectors.

Comment: Right, most are things like GridViewMarks$ctl02$<name>, no name is repeated because of the scheme the GridView uses to generate the names.  But all the ones I'm looking for have "import<number>" at the end, even though I don't know the beginning of the ID.

Comment: So, since I can't use styles for selecting in older IEs, and assigning width with a CSS class doesn't seem to work in any browser, the best practice is a dummy class just for selection in jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I set a simple class with only the width attribute, and it didn't work in Chrome, Safari, FF, or IE.  In the developer's tools I can see that the class is there, and it's found in the CSS file with the correct attribute, but it's doing nothing. :(

Comment: @Brandon -- try using `width: 100% !important;`

Answer (score -1):

This fiddle works on IE8 (also in IE7 mode in IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/jaPyK/

I seem to be getting the object fine with your selectors. I'm using jQUery 1.6. though.

Comment: try `alert($('span[style*="width:100%"]').length);` in IE 8 and you get `0`

Comment: I forgot that the project is using jQuery 1.4.4, so I tried a newer version, but to no avail.  I am using IE9, pressing F12, and setting the Browser Mode to IE8, and typing directly into the console; it's returning nothing still.

Comment: Oops, forgot to check the length! Yes, for some reason, style-width seems to not work. I updated the fiddle to select on name and that works: http://jsfiddle.net/jaPyK/2/